# Magnetic field lines intersect?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I know that two magnetic field lines never intersect. However, I noticed that the radial magnetic field produced by two curved magnets has a point  where all the magnetic field lines intersect, i.e. the center, as shown in the figure. Can anyone explain why it is so?
[image: radial magnetic field]

Comment: Because the figure is inaccurate.

Comment: what should be the correct depiction of radial magnetic field?

Comment: At the center, a homogeneous horizontal field. I'm also extremely skeptical of the behaviour near the edges (i.e. where N and S are in close proximity).